# how to get total user count monthwise mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get total user count in mySQL by Grouping by month

I want to list the total count of registered users grouped by month.

The difficulty about this is that I want count of all the months between a range necessarily with count as 0 if there's no data during any month.

**My code**

```
SELECT tots.*, @var := @var + tots.`count` as totalCount
  FROM (
     SELECT
        YEAR(registered) AS `year`,
        MONTH(registered) AS `month`,
        COUNT(*) AS `count`
     FROM user where id = 73
          AND registered >= '2017-01-01'
          AND registered <= '2017-05-01'
     GROUP BY `year`, `month`
  )
AS tots, (SELECT @var := 0) AS inc
```

**Current Output**

```
+------+-------+-------+-------------+
| Year | Month | Count | TotalCount  |
+------+-------+-------+-------------+
| 2017 | 01    | 1     | 1           |
| 2017 | 04    | 4     | 5           |
+------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

**Preferred Output**

```
+------+-------+-------+-------------+
| Year | Month | Count | TotalCount  |
+------+-------+-------+-------------+
| 2017 | 01    | 1     | 1           |
| 2017 | 02    | 0     | 1           |
| 2017 | 03    | 0     | 1           |
| 2017 | 04    | 1     | 2           |
| 2017 | 05    | 0     | 2           |
+------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Here **Count** is total new user in that month and **TotalCount** is total user up to that month.

The NULL results ARE necessary.

How could I achieve that result in mySQL or in Laravel PHP?

Comment: Output output output. How about some input?

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't get you.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you have at least one user registered in each month.  If so, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT tots.*, (@var := @var + tots.`count`) as totalCount
FROM (SELECT YEAR(registered) AS `year`, MONTH(registered) AS `month`,
             SUM( id = 73 ) AS `count`
      FROM user 
      WHERE registered >= '2017-01-01' AND registered <= '2017-05-01'
      GROUP BY `year`, `month`
     ) tots CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @var := 0) AS params;
```

Otherwise you need a calendar table or a way of generating one row per month.

Comment: Thanks. This code is also giving the same output as my current output.

Comment: @Rajeev . . . So you have some year/month combos were *no* users have data, not just user `73`.  In that case, you need a calendar table or some other ways to generate all months.